# How to add colored overlay effect for images with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, overlay

I am trying to add an overlay effect for each image on a webpage. Basically when the cursor is moved over the image, it will slightly change color. However the desired effect is not occurring. What is the best way to fix this?

Here is a picture of the webpage for context.

[image]

**HTML**

```
    <div class="service-box">
        <div class="single-service">
            <img src="images/facials.PNG">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="single-service">
            <img src="images/skin_solutions.PNG"> 
            <div class="overlay"></div>  
        </div>
        <div class="single-service">
            <img src="images/lash.PNG">
            <div class="overlay"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="single-service">
            <img src="images/microblading.PNG">
            <div class="overlay"></div> 
        </div>
        <div class="single-service">
            <img src="images/eyebrow_treatment.PNG">
            <div class="overlay"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.service-box{
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: auto;
}
.single-service{
    flex-basis: 50%; /*get two services in 1 row*/
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.single-service img{
    width: 85%; /*resize image*/
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.overlay{
    width: 100%
    height 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),#93dced);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}

.single-service:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well, but there is a technical error in the css, in the `.overlay` class. You skipped it `;` after `width: 100%`, and missed `:` between `height: 100%`.

It should be like this:

```
.overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),#93dced);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to be more careful about syntax errors.

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This will make your images 60% transparent when hovered over.

```
  img:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),#93dced);
    opacity: 60%;
    transition: 1s;}
```